# KDB/Q sequence generation similar to R's seq(from, to, step)

Tags: kdb

Is there a way to generate sequence of number with a given step, similar to R's seq(from, to, step) function?

e.g.

```
> seq(1,20,2)   
[1]  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Comment: I tried something like `tils:{[start;end;step] l:start+til end;l where (l mod step) in 0}` but modulo should be applied to element indexes, not the elements themselves.

Comment: I wish I could give more than one accepted answer as both jglesson and @terrylynch answers nail it. Thanks to the alternative solutions authors as well for the education value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

user2393012's answer is close, but not exactly what question was looking for. The below works well -

```
q)seq:{x+z*til ceiling(1+y-x)%z}
q)seq[1;20;2]
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative (but not better than the simpler arithmetic solutions)

```
q){-1_(y>=)(z+)\x}[1;20;2]
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
```

Comment: Nicely done Terry! One edge case - try `{-1_(y>)(z+)\x}[10;50;10]`. Shouldn't the 50 be included? I would suggest changing to `(y>=)`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use arithmetic :-)

```
q){[step;start;length] start+step*til length}[2;0;10]
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18
q){[step;start;length] start+step*til length}[3;0;10]
0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option (slight variation of [terrylynch solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31588253/5620913)):

```
q) {(z+)\[floor(y-x)%z;x]} [1;20;2]
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19
```